# Does node.js itself have production mode

Tags: node.js, development-environment, production-environment

Are there any differences between development or production mode in node itself? By that I mean, for example the error stack depth is smaller or more caching levels take place to optimize performance or something like that?

Comment: https://nodejs.dev/learn/nodejs-the-difference-between-development-and-production

Comment: @nicholaswmin I read that article, but it seems to me that they are speaking in general sense. And after that they immediately mention Pug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. NODE_ENV is only a convention in the ecosystem. Node.js itself does not rely on it. [Here is resource](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3306#issuecomment-814104609).